# How do you manage large C++ dependencies in a team environment?

Tags: c++, build-automation, tfsbuild, dependency-management

**BACKGROUND**

Over the course of my career I have been surprised by how many projects I've seen where it is a real challenge to compile and execute a project in Visual Studio.  The source of the problem generally is due to: missing dependencies, lack of documentation, broken project references, etc.

To avoid these headaches I try to automate projects/solutions such that:

1. the run-time environment is automatically setup when a project is compiled on the developer machine (e.g. use batch scripts to import missing Windows Registry keys)
2. when compiling a project, the correct dependencies are automatically retrieved (on both the build machine & the developer machines)

**THE PROBLEM**

To date, I have had a fair amount of success with this approach. However, I have recently been handed a native C++ project that has a dependency on the Microsoft Windows SDK.  At compile time, the project makes use of Windows environment variables to locate missing dependencies (e.g. Microsoft Windows SDK).

I understand that using environment variables is how things used to be done.  However, by relying on the software developer to configure the development environment:

- you are assuming that they will configure the environment properly
- the developer is wasting time on configuration when their time could be better spent developing

I do not want to debate the merits of having a developer configure the development environment, but rather, I would like to know:

> Given the technology (e.g. TFS) that exists today, what is a reliable and repeatable approach to handling large dependencies (e.g. Windows SDK) for C++ projects in a team environment?

**POTENTIAL SOLUTIONS**

1. **continue to use environment variables**

   - Adv: once the dependencies are installed, it is very easy for the build machine to compile projects
   - Dis: you have to spend time documenting to ensure that you can configure the build machine from scratch (e.g. step1: install dependency A, step2: install dependency B, etc.)
   - Dis: You are relying on the *magic* environment variables to be pointing at the right target.
   - Dis: the developer is wasting time configuring when they should be developing
2. **check dependencies into TFS**

   - Adv: everything is kept in one centralized location
   - Adv: by design, source control keeps a history
   - Adv: in a sense, source control makes things self-documenting
   - Dis: Compiling on the build machine now takes considerably longer as the build machine 
     workspace has to repeatedly retrieve the Windows SDK from TFS
3. **Other?**

**CONTEXT**

- Programming Language: unmanaged C++
- Source Control: TFS 2012
- Dependencies:

  - Microsoft Windows SDK (~416Mb)
  - in house libraries
- I have limited knowledge of how to administer/configure the TFS build machine.

**REFERENCES**

- Microsoft: [Team Development with Visual Studio TFS (Chapter 6)](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Have you considered leaving things as they are and providing tools to help configuring/detect misconfiguration? i.e. provide a script that will detect whether the SDK can be found and yield a user-friendly error message: "Install Windows SDK and/or setup environment var XXX to point to the correct path"

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Hi David.  Thank you for taking the time to reply. Yes this option is also on the table.

Answer (score 1):

I remember while working for a security company, the team had a script that usually copies all dependencies for you as soon as you hit compile, to a specific folder for you. its in build properties, for an MFC project, however, it was confusing to me at the time.

the reference seemed very helpful thank you

Comment: I have used this in the past, and while it required more hard drive space, having the ability to just checkout the project from the repository, run a script that would download from a server all dependencies, build and pack in a single step was wonderful

Comment: right now we have interns whom spend all their time learning python and write scripts to manage source code, or anything needed for project, such as configuring new machines. I never experience that, but python seemed very powerful tool